# How to reference the value of an attribute in an XML

Tags: xml, xslt

How do I reference the value passed in the ID field of an XML in a corresponding when statement in an XSLT?

Snippet of XML:

```
<UserArea>
  <Id idOwner="Timekeeper"> 
      <IdValue>Time</IdValue> 
  </Id> 
</UserArea>
```

I want to build a conditional statement (using Choose Statement) based on the IdValue that is passed.
Everything I build does not seem to recognize the conditional statement I build for the When statement.  I've tried several different syntax but nothing seems to work, however, I do not get a syntax error- it just seems to never go into the node and evaluate it as True. The latest I have is:

```
<xsl:when test="hr:Timekeeper = 'Time'">
```

I'm also not sure what the "hr" means in this statement.. I copied that from a previous person that worked on this XSLT.

All my IF statements work but not the above WHEN statement.  A sample IF statement that works perfectly in the same XSLT is:

```
<xsl:if test="@idOwner = 'Timekeeper' and hr:IdValue !=''">
  ....do something
</xsl:if>
```

In this syntax is it correct that the '@' standards for attribute?

I'm a novice at building XSLT's and I mainly only have to make very small edits to existing XSLT's but this is the first one I have to do much more than just small edits.

thxs!

Answer (score 3):

XSLT uses a query syntax called XPath, so I would recommend reading up on XPath i order to fully understand how this works.

In XPath you use the `@` prefix to denote attributes, so the following should work:

```
<xsl:when test="@idOwner = 'Timekeeper'">
```

This will test whether the `idOwner` attribute is equal to `Timekeeper` for the current node.

Comment: thank you for the recommendation but one additional question. How do I reference the value that is nested in the Timekeeper attribute to build a conditional statement based on it?  Is that possible?

Comment: @user2756253 XPath is your friend. It is well worth learning. http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation and I will definitely review it again. Meanwhile, I have to get this done for a customer by friday. Can't get fully up to speed on it in one day :).  I've actually worked with XSLT's for about 2 years.. this is the first I've encountered where I haven't been able to figure out the issue.  I've literally done all the same codes that have been presented to me in this post prior to receiving the answer.  since I'm getting the same answers that I've already tried something else must be wrong that I haven't been able to identify.  Thanks again.  calling it a night.

Answer (score 1):

the hr: is a namespace you won't need it for the example
in addition to the answer of ColinE the content of a node is the textnode, so your test statement should look like this:

```
<xsl:when test="@idOwner = 'Timekeeper' and IdValue/text() != ''>
```

Comment: Thanks for the additional coding but it still does not work.  In my Choose statement it always defaults to the "Otherwise" statement.  I'm at least on the right path with googling XPATH versus XML searches. :) But it still does not evaluate this condition to true.  

    <xsl:when test="@idOwner = 'Timekeeper' and IdValue/text()= 'Time'">

    <xsl:if test="@idOwner = 'Managers_Email_ID' and hr:IdValue !=''"> 
      <Person>
          <Name>Manager</Name>
        <Value><xsl:value-of select="hr:IdValue"/></Value>
      </Person>
       </xsl:if>

Comment: I'm a bit confused with your code because your mixing xsl:when and xsl:if Perhaps you just post a snippet of your xml and your complete xsl

Answer (score 1):

XPath expressions rely on prefixes to denote namespaced elements. Unprefixed names always refer to elements in no namespace. I suspect your input XML has a default namespace declaration like

```
xmlns="http://ns.hr-xml.org"
```

which puts all the elements in a namespace. So your XSLT has a matching declaration on the `xsl:stylesheet` to bind the same namespace URI to a prefix

```
xmlns:hr="http://ns.hr-xml.org"
```

so you can use `hr:IdValue` in xpath to select the `IdValue` element in the `http://ns.hr-xml.org` namespace.

An `xmlns="..."` doesn't apply to attributes, which is why you don't need to prefix the `idOwner` attribute name.

The exact expressions you need to use depend on the *current context*. If you're in a context where the current node is the `Id` element (e.g. directly inside an `<xsl:template match="hr:Id">`) and you want to test the value of the idOwner you'd use

```
test="@idOwner = 'Timekeeper'"
```

For the IdValue

```
test="hr:IdValue = 'Time'"
```

and for both together use `and`

```
test="@idOwner = 'Timekeeper' and hr:IdValue = 'Time'"
```

If the current context is the parent UserArea element and you want to check whether it *has* an Id matching these constraints then you'd use

```
test="hr:Id[@idOwner = 'Timekeeper' and hr:IdValue = 'Time']"
```

Comment: Are you referring to this:
xmlns="http://ns.hr-xml.org"> ?
Unfortunately this xml has been in use for several years. I'm only adding soe additional logic to it to account for multiple scenarios.  I can't quite tell my customer that there XML is incorrect at this stage because I can't get this statement syntax correct. :) But I believe what you are referencing is there.
Perhaps what my customer wants can't be done... I have a few senior people looking at this at my job and they did not have a specific solution either- and they are developers :)

Comment: Hi Ian... I feel like such a pain so please forgive me.  I tried this solution:

    test="@idOwner = 'Timekeeper' and hr:IdValue = 'Time`"

Literally 6 hours ago (no kidding)
That also did not work.. it seems to truly just not recognize the Conditional statement.

    <xsl:when test="@idOwner = 'Timekeeper' and hr:IdValue = 'Time`">

I will try it again before I give up.

Comment: @user2756253 it's context-dependent. I've added another example to see if that makes things clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if anyone is even viewing this post any longer but I ended up having to build a function in the XSLT to reference the conditions that I need to address.  I had several senior people working on this with me (been coding far far far longer than myself) and they also could not get our choose statement to work.  It was resolved by abandoning our original plan and building a function call in the XSLT to determine what name should populate the node.